# Is there a way to backup OnLive data for use on a PC?

Tags: onlive

I expect the answer to be no but, I'm asking just in case I'm wrong. One case that I can see such a thing being useful would be if a person were to be away from an OnLive worthy Internet connection and wanted to continue to play a game that were owned by one of their friends.

In my case, I'd be equipped with a laptop with said game while vacationing in an area with a slow DSL connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is definitely no current way to get any data in to or out of OnLive.

It's one of the downsides of "cloud gaming". On the upload side, they don't want you adding any data to their servers that might mess up their gaming utopia. On the download side, games on OnLive are a custom build to integrate with the OnLive systems (inputs, achievements, brag clips, etc) and might not even share the same save file format. Aside from that, it's just more work that developers would have to do before they release a game on the OnLive platform.